# Keycloal Social Login and Custom Login Authenticator

Tags: keycloak

I am using keycloak as security layer and working towards enabling social login.
Social login was working and I was able to integrate Facebook with just configurations using the doicuments.

However I have a requirement where in I need to provide an API end points for the same.
Our mobile devices will be communicating to facebook via the app and will have the token from the facebook (Implicit Flow).
I will then be exchanging the token with keycloak for the keycloak access token.

I have two questions:

1. Is this approach correct? If not why?
2. How can I achieve this?

   I was thinking of writing a custom authenticator (Am not sure if thats the right approoach as I have to register user are well if FB Access token user is not available with us (We can afford to login user and with jsut emailID as we can onbaord new users later)

I am blocked because authenticator is not working with any build from 2.4.0 onwards

Let me know if my approach is correct and if so how to proceed about it.